# Match expression with regex until - followed by alphabet?

Tags: python, regex

I have strings with multiple dash characters, and I want the get the expression until the dash only if the dash is followwd by alphabet and not by numeric.

I have used

```
re.search("^([^-])+","3x130-140k-ZZ-ABC")
```

but it returns  `3x130` which is until the first dash but I want `3x130-140k` because only the second dash is followed by alphabet.

I want a regex which returns `3x130-140k` from  `3x130-140k-ZZ-ABC`   and returns `3x140k`  from `3x140k-ZZ-ABC` .

Comment: I mean any letter, upper or lower case. The point is that tle letter is right after the dash

Comment: Two questions: (1) by "dash is followed by alphabet" do you mean that the whole word that follows the dash (until the next dash) should be made of letters, or that the next character directly after the dash should be a letter?   (2) If no dash in the string satisfied the condition, what do you want to return? Nothing, an empty string, or the whole string?

Comment: Answers:(1) just the next character (2)the whole string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
^.*?(?=-[A-Za-z])
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dlZocH/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `.*?` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars as few as possible
- `(?=-[A-Za-z])` - a location that is immediately followed with `-` and an ASCII letter (use `(?=-[^\W\d_])` to match any Unicode letter).

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/YBu0Fx):

```py
import re
text = "3x130-140k-ZZ-ABC"
m = re.search(r"^.*?(?=-[A-Za-z])", text)
if m:
    print(m.group()) # => 3x130-140k
```

Comment: @ranemak Great, note that a negated character class like `[^-]*` cannot be used here, since you need to match any `-` that is not followed by a letter, however, it s a good construct to bear in mind as it is quite efficient. However, `^([^-]*(?:-(?![A-Za-z])[^-]*)*)-[A-Za-z]` can probably be used too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use -[a-zA-Z] to match a dash and then a letter. Then you can take the portion of the string before this match:

```
import re
raw_string = "3x130-140k-ZZ-ABC"
match = re.search("-[a-zA-z]", raw_string)
print(raw_string[:match.start()])
```

Output:

```
3x130-140k
```

Comment: Looks good but someimes special characters can be in the string too

Answer (score 0):

No need for a regexp. Use `str.split(txt, '-')` to split on dashes, then use `next` to find the index of the first dash followed by a word that satisfies `word.isalpha()`.

```py
def eat_until_dash_alphaword(txt, dash='-'):
    words = txt.split(dash)
    i = next((i for i in range(1, len(words)+1) if words[i].isalpha()), None)  # whole word is alpha
    #i = next((i for i in range(1, len(words)+1) if words[i][0].isalpha()), None)  # first char is alpha
    if i is not None:
        return dash.join(words[:i])
    else:
        return txt # or raise an error, or return empty string

print(eat_until_dash_alphaword("3x130-140k-ZZ-ABC"))
# 3x130-140k
```

If you want to find the first dash followed by *at least one* alpha character, then it's even simpler. You don't need `str.split` at all, just a simple iteration on the characters:

```py
from itertools import pairwise

def eat_until_dash_alphachar(txt, dash='-'):
    for i, (a, b) in enumerate(pairwise(txt)):
        if a == dash and b.isalpha():
            return txt[:i]
    return txt # or raise an error, or return empty string

print(eat_until_dash_alphachar("3x130-140k-ZZ-ABC"))
# 3x130-140k
```

Comment: It pretty complicated compered to the previous answers but thanks for your effort!!

Comment: @ranemak A matter of taste, I suppose. Personally I find it simpler. It iterates on the characters until it finds a pair of characters `a, b` such that `a` is `'-'` and `b` is alphabetical. Condition `if a == dash and b.isalpha():` is quite explicit.

Answer (score 0):

You might also [split](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.split) on the first occurrence of a hyphen followed by a char `[a-zA-Z]` and limit the *maxsplit* to 1.

```
import re

strings = [
    "3x130-140k-ZZ-ABC",
    "3x140k-ZZ-ABC"
]
pattern = r"-[a-zA-Z]"
for s in strings:
    print(re.split(pattern, s, 1)[0])
```

Output

```
3x130-140k
3x140k
```

Comment: @ranemak You are welcome. Note that from 15 [reputation points](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you have the possibility to upvote all the answers that have been proven helpful.